# ASP.Net/VB.Net/LINQ: Unable to cast object of type .objectquery to type generic.list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I have a question about ASP.Net, visual basic
I have 2 LINQ query's, the first one works, the second one doesnt, produces a

```
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'1[SelmaV2.Products]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]'.
```

Heres the code:

```
Sub GetProducts(ByRef productDropList As DropDownList)
    Dim productList As New List(Of String)
    Using context As New SelmaEntities
        productList = (From products In context.Products
                       Order By products.Product
                       Select products.Product).Distinct.ToList()
    End Using
    productDropList.DataSource = productList
End Sub
Sub GetProductNames(ByRef ProductNamesList As List(Of String), ByVal CurrentProduct As String)
    Using context As New SelmaEntities
        ProductNamesList = (From products In context.Products
                            Where products.Product = CurrentProduct
                            Order By products.Product_no Ascending
                            Select products).ToList
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you're trying to get a list of *strings*, but it looks like you're selecting a list of *products*. I suspect you want something like

```
Select products.Product
```

instead of

```
Select products
```

in the query. (Your naming is also somewhat unfortunate, as `products` will still only refer to a single product at a time - I would rename that range variable to `product`, personally.)

Comment: Wow, that was just a huge silly mistake by me, I wanted to get products.Product_no. Thank you very much, I was thinking that results will go just products.